# Serverless Authentication: Auth0 at Lambda@Edge triggered by Cloudfront Viewer request protecting S3 Bucket. Infinity Redirect loop

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-cloudfront, auth0, aws-lambda-edge

### Context

I have a S3 bucket with static files. In front of this bucket, i have Cloudfront, triggering a lambda@edge function on each viewer request. My lambda function is based on this following project:

https://github.com/Widen/cloudfront-auth

What i want: Make my S3 bucket acessible only after login (I'm using AUTH 0).

### Issue

After login screen, i get a infinity loop of redirects between auth0/cloudfront and recieve too_many_requests:

[image: Error]

### Configs

#### Lambda

```json
{
    "AUTH_REQUEST": {
        "client_id": "<myId>",
        "response_type": "code",
        "scope": "openid email",
        "redirect_uri": "https://<myCF>.cloudfront.net"
    },
    "TOKEN_REQUEST": {
        "client_id": "<myId>",
        "client_secret": "<myRandomGeneratedSecret>",
        "redirect_uri": "https://<myCF>.cloudfront.net",
        "grant_type": "authorization_code"
    },
    "DISTRIBUTION": "serverlessAuth",
    "AUTHN": "AUTH0",
    "PRIVATE_KEY": "<KEY>",
    "PUBLIC_KEY": "<KEY>",
    "DISCOVERY_DOCUMENT": "https://<myAuth0>.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    "SESSION_DURATION": 259200,
    "BASE_URL": "https://<myAuth0>.us.auth0.com",
    "CALLBACK_PATH": "/_callback",
    "AUTHZ": "AUTH0"
}
```

#### CloudFront Config

[image: cf]

#### Auth0 Config

Only social connection with google Enabled:

[image: cnf]

Seems to be working fine, testing inside auth0 connection test:

[image: gcnf]

My Auth0 Config:

[image: cnf]

#### Additional Info:

My Cloudfront redirects to a S3 bucket with static files (docusaurus generated).

#### FF Tools:

My requests keeps in a infinity loop 'till error:

[image: error]

Can someone help me? What i'm doing wrong? I'm almost giving up :/